# How to make bootable usb from .imz file?

Tags: 14.04, boot

I am using this tool, but I don't have Windows machine anymore. Is there any way to make bootable USB from .imz files? 
Any ideas, how to do that?

Comment: `imz` format files are pkzip compressed.

Comment: decompress it and dd it to a device. maybe there is a single command for that

Comment: Rinzwid, any tips how to do that?

Comment: I would start with `gunzip`. (this might help too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154577/what-is-a-linux-equivalent-to-pkzip-or-winzip-or-the-gui-version-of-7zip )

Comment: Any command's to do that in easiest way? I decompress that file, what's next? how to transfer to USB?